# Word meaning romantic but without conveying the idea of love?

Tags: single-word-requests

Example:

> He drowned. It wasn't anything [...], like he wasn't surfing or rescuing someone
>   at the moment. He just slipped and fell into the water.

I'm looking for something closer to *heroic* and *idyllic*. Like stuff that you see in movies or novels.

Comment: I don't see what might be *romantic*, *elegant*, nor *idyllic* about drowning whilst swimming, nor for that matter, whilst rescuing someone.

Comment: @WS2 Sorry, I meant *heroic*.

Comment: *Epic, grand, awesome.*

Comment: Stuff you see in books and movies is _dramatized_. If I focus on that part of your question, I'd suggest that his drowning was nothing **dramatic**.

Comment: Is there any reason not to use _romantic_? According to the context, it may or may not convey the idea of love. In this context, it does not.

Comment: Surfing and rescuing someone are two quite different things. If you were just to use the latter, then *heroic* would fit perfectly. *Dramatic* might fit with surfing. But your problem is that the two activities call for different treatments. Aside from that, I don't like the expression *like he wasn't surfing...etc*. It is idiomatic at a certain level, but it is a very sloppy way of speaking and not really grammatical. I think I would just leave out the word *like*. You could put a *for example* between commas, after *wasn't* but it isn't essential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to suggest there was nothing heroic or adventurous about the death:

It was an *ordinary* drowning. He slipped and fell into the water.

P.S. If you want to express it in the negative:

**There was *nothing adventurous* in the death; it involved no risk-taking or heroics. He merely slipped and fell into the water, and was gone.**

Answer (score 1):

The most fitting synonyms have already been suggested, such as Cerberus' "epic", "grand" and "awesome" and Tim Romano's "adventurous".

However, if you should decide to go the opposite way and emphasize how un-romantic the drowning was, you can use ***"[Mundane](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mundane)"*** (ordinary, dull - according to MW-Online):

> "He drowned. It wasn't anything romantic, like he wasn't surfing or rescuing someone at the moment. He just slipped and fell into the water...sadly, it was simply a mundane drowning."

Answer (score 1):

**Glorious** seems to cover the bases here. By that, I mean it has more than one meaning, which some of the other suggestions don't:

1. delightful; wonderful; completely enjoyable - as surfing might be.
2. full of glory; entitled to great renown - as rescuing someone (being heroic) would be.

Many of the synonyms have a tendency to lean one direction or the other and don't capture the fuller sense that you are trying to convey by way of your example sentence.

(definitions from Dictionary.com)

Answer (score 1):

Another suggestion would be ***sensational***:

> : causing very great excitement or interest with shocking details
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster online](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sensational)</sub>

Alternatively, ***memorable***:

> : very good or interesting and worth remembering
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster online](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/memorable)</sub>

Or, ***remarkable***:

> : unusual or surprising : likely to be noticed
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster online](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/remarkable)</sub>

Each seems to fit well into your usage:

> He drowned. It wasn't anything *sensational*, ...
>   He drowned. It wasn't anything *memorable*, ...
>   He drowned. It wasn't anything *remarkable*, ...

Answer (score 0):

> He drowned. It wasn't anything **melodramatic** or **tragical**, like he wasn't surfing or rescuing someone at the moment.

[**melodramatic**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/melodramatic)
1. of, like, or befitting melodrama.
2. exaggeratedly emotional or sentimental; disproportionately intense.
<sub>Webster's College Dictionary</sub>

**[tragic](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Tragic)**  or *tragical*
Adj.1.  tragic - very sad tragic - very sad; especially involving grief or death or destruction; "a tragic face"; "a tragic plight"; "a tragic accident"
<sub>WordNet 3.0,</sub>

---

Neither of these words mean anything close to *romantic* with or without the connotations of *love*, but then again sudden death rarely is.